# Custom ActionBar NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, actionbar

У меня TabActivity и я хочу создать custom action bar, но возникают такие ошибки:

> 04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.bonsitelazyl/com.example.bonsitelazyl.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.bonsitelazyl/com.example.bonsitelazyl.News}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 04-25 20:33:15.186:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 04-25 20:33:15.186:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 04-25 20:33:15.186:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-25 20:33:15.186:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12242): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable
>   to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.bonsitelazyl/com.example.bonsitelazyl.News}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 04-25 20:33:15.186:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1917)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:682)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:346) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236) 04-25 20:33:15.186:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   com.example.bonsitelazyl.MainActivity.addTab(MainActivity.java:47)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   com.example.bonsitelazyl.MainActivity.setTabs(MainActivity.java:29)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   com.example.bonsitelazyl.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): ... 11 more 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 04-25 20:33:15.186:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   com.example.bonsitelazyl.News.onCreate(News.java:15) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479) 04-25
>   20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
>   04-25 20:33:15.186: E/AndroidRuntime(12242): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    TabHost tabHost;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabHost = getTabHost();  
        setTabs();
    } 

    private void setTabs() 
    { 
        addTab("", R.drawable.tab_news, News.class); 
        addTab("", R.drawable.tab_servises, News.class);
        addTab("", R.drawable.tab_profile, News.class);
        addTab("", R.drawable.tab_contacts, News.class);
    }

    private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
    { 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
        TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(labelId);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon); 
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);      
        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

News

```
public class News extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_n);

        ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: из логов ничего не понятно. Попробуйте их отформатировать как-то. Плюс, попробуйте сделать getSupportActionBar();

Comment: NullPointerException в методе addTab в 47 строке

Comment: на какой именно строке возникает NPE?

Comment: @metalurgus на `ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();`

Comment: нет, не там. оно падает на 47 строке в addTab(). что находится на 47 строке?

Comment: @metalurgus находится `tabHost.addTab(spec);`

Comment: значит tabhost = null

Comment: @metalurgus если я в классе `News` убираю все с `ActionBar mActionBar...` до конца `mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);` тогда ошибки нет

Comment: @metalurgus если вывести `tabHost`  в Log то он не null